# Different revenue models between developers and publishers?

Tags: publishing, revenue, business-model

I am working at a small game studio developing games for iOS and Android. We do the full journey here, from idea to finished product and we have funding to do so. However, with the smartphone market being a bit of a lottery for small developers we are looking into getting into a publisher deal.

What I am wondering now is what kind of different deals one could look at. From what I have gathered from reading a number of articles a common model it is that the publisher pay for the development cost and once the game is released the developer gets about 20% of the revenue. What I am wondering is if there are any other common models used between developers and publishers?

Answer (score 2):

In general nature of the Developer-Publisher relationship, it is true that the developer will make the game at a loss to themselves and then receive compensation from the publisher. 20% of the revenue however seems first fairly high to me, and second it is -very- easy to show how very little 'revenue' is being generated by something to make this kind of agreement even more frustrating. You may want to consider alternates that are more tangible or lump sum payments for completion (given), target sales ranges, completion dates met, etc. Also, depending on how long your development cycles are, you might want to negotiate milestone deliverables and payment schedule, so its not an all or nothing sort of deal. Split the development cycle into 3 substantial collections of functionality and upon completing terms of the each deliverable you would receive partial payments towards the development costs.

Another large thing to be aware of, almost every publisher -will- require you to give them ownership of any IP they are publishing, regardless of who came up with the idea. Make sure the terms in that area are well understood by all parties.

Hope this helps.

Comment: did you actually mean to say this?  "the developer will make the game at a loss to themselves and then receive compensation from the developer"

Comment: @ultifinitus Yes. What this means is that if it costs you more to finish the game than you contracted with the publisher for, you will eat those losses as well.

Comment: I had assumed you meant to substitute the second "developer" with "publisher"

Comment: Oh, LOL Yes I had, I will edit that in there correctly now.. Apologies :)

Comment: I appreciate your input @James. However, I am still looking for more alternative ways in which both we as a developer and our publisher could divide the revenue from our upcoming game. As I mentioned - the development is being financed from another party then our publisher. So what we are really looking for with them is help with marketing. Considering that they are not paying for the development cost we are interested in finding different ways of dividing the revenue between us.

Comment: @Annica If you are just looking for the marketing aspect of a publisher you would likely be better off to just seek out an entertainment media marketing company and work with them directly. You will really want to go to a publisher when you either need to fund the development of a project or access to their Console environments (not always easy to get from Microsoft/Sony/Nintendo as an Indy), QA or the like.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The notion of a "publisher" is often somewhat different for mobile (iOS/Android) games. While the situation described in this answer is usually what "publisher" means for AAA and/or console games, mobile "publishers" are often more like a marketing company (ie. what you recommend in your comment) that specializes in (and thus has a lot of domain knowledge about) games.

Comment: The publishers for AAA titles are also the ones who do the marketing @jhocking. The key difference between a marketing company and a publisher however is going to be what they do with the game. Publishers will want to own part of the game in one way or another as opposed to just getting the name out there. By the comments of Annica, they are going to share the revenue and that is just a normal publisher. Not a company hired for a price point to do an advertising campaign.

Comment: Yes I know AAA publishers do the marketing too. I never said they didn't. Your answer gave a description of a publisher; I'm saying that description is more applicable to AAA publishers than mobile publishers. Among other things, mobile publishers generally don't take ownership of the IP.

Comment: @James
What might be the deals with publishers with respect to IP?
In my case, I have the design and development complete for a game and looking for a publisher who can provide concept art and publish the game.
So, if I would not like to give complete rights on the IP, what kind of deal can I look upto?

Comment: @SriSwetha Sorry for the long response time. I wish I could be more helpful but the deal with a publisher will honestly come down to what you can find and negotiate for. I live in USA and here it is a very common practice that Publishers own the IP. That is not the case else-where in the world and is changing all of the time. If you are also expecting the publisher to provide artists (concept art) then that is even more of a negotiation and honestly might be better for you to find an artist that suits your needs on your own. Good Luck!